# Listing the available installation of depothelper (HP-UX)

Tags: package-management, hp-ux

I'm using depothelper to install software in HP-UX.
So far, I was only able to search for packages using common sense and intuition.
I would like to know if there's a way to tell which packages are available for installation (like yum list or apt-cache search).

The man page doesn't specify an option like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, turns out it's the list that can be found here:
http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/auto/summary_all.html